# jQuery and jQuery multi file upload scripts are not loading

Tags: sharepoint-online

Done with development and moved to production. Working everything in development, after moving to production, I am getting errors like $(...).MultiFile is not a function even though the script is referred. Just copied through designer all site pages/assets to new site.

Answer (score 0):

Hit F12 and view the network tab in the development console while refreshing the page. Look for the jquery files you're referencing and verify that they are being loaded correctly, and aren't resulting in not found messages due to invalid paths.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

As you are using jquery and jquery multifile plugin on same page, this might be causing jquery conflict with other libraries.

**Solution**

You can use `Query.noConflict()` in such cases. `jQuery.noConflict`  will reset the `$` variable so it's no longer an alias of  `jQuery`. Aside from just calling it once, there's not much else you really need to do. Though, you can create your own alias with the return value, if you'd like:

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

And, generally, you want to do this right after including jQuery and any plugins:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/prototype.js"></script>
```

You can also go one step further and free up `jQuery` with `noConflict(true)`. Though, if you take this route, you'll definitely want an alias as neither `$` nor `jQuery` will probably be what you want:

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

**Reference**

[Avoid conflicts with other libraries](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/).

Answer (score 0):

Please create a new page and test with the simple snippet below to check if it works:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/dev/SiteAssets/jquery.MultiFile.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    // invoke plugin
    $('#our-test').MultiFile({
        onFileChange: function(){
            console.log(this, arguments);
        }
    });

});

</script>
<input name="files[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" class="maxsize-1024" id="our-test" />
```

[image]

And make sure jquery.MultiFile.min.js has been moved to Production environment.